# I am unable to click this dropdown and get the element item (GMT -8:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada) can anyone help me out

Tags: automation, cypress

[image]

I am not able to write a selector for this dropdown I used code like:

```
SelectTimeZone()
   {
    const drop = cy.xpath("//div[@class='select-container']//select[@name='Time Zone']")
    drop.select('Choose one').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

`cy.xpath()` will be asynchronous, so you can't use it like this, you have to chain it like it's usually done in Cypress:

```js
cy
  .xpath("//div[@class='select-container']//select[@name='Time Zone']")
  .select('-08:00');
```

Another problem is what string you sent to `.select()` method. If you want to choose some time value, you have to use e.g. a value or text of the appropriate option.

---

I'd also try to avoid xPath as much as I can, it's not very readable, this selector might work just fine:

```js
cy
  .get("[name='Time Zone']")
  .select('-08:00');
```